# How to disable trackpad two finger swipe forward/backward using javascript or html

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, trackpad

I have an app, which changes the url when moved from one state to another state, like from home/#state to home/#state2. When i do i two finger swipe using trackpad from home/#state2, page is going back to home/#state1 which i don't want to happen.

Is there anyway to disable this feature by listening on any specific events ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
history.pushState(null, null, 'pagename');
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
history.pushState(null, null, 'pagename');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this using, browser url stack. When I swipe forward/backward using trackpad on a web page, the relative urls are added to the previous/next urls list in browser. So I have overwritten the behavior to not add relative urls and to previous/next urls list and also remove the relative urls in the application i am implementing.